# How to color scatter plot points that meet 2 or more conditions in different columns in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, scatter-plot

Here is a part of a dataframe that I have

| value1 | value2 | condition1 | condition2 | condition3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.3 | 0.1 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 3.5 | 2.6 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 3.1 | 2.5 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 3.2 | 2.3 | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 2.4 | 1.1 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2.7 | 2.2 | FALSE | TRUE | FALSE |
| 2.5 | 3 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 2.9 | 2 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |
| 4.2 | 1 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE |
| 2.2 | 1.5 | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE |

**I would like to plot a scatter plot of value1 vs value2 and color the points that have 2 or more TRUE conditions,**

Do you have any suggestions on how to do this(using ggplot2 and the tidyverse)? Thank you for your time and help

I have tried to group the conditions with group_by but I have not been successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may get the color by using `rowSums` on the condition columns and then use `plot` from `base R`

```
colr <- ifelse(rowSums(df1[3:5]) > 1, "red", "black")
plot(df1$value1, df1$value2, col = colr, xlab = "value1", ylab = "value2")
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, create colour column based on `rowSums` on the logical columns, then use `geom_point` with `colour = colr` column and add `scale_colour_identity()`to use the already existing scaled data

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(colr = case_when(rowSums(across(starts_with("condition"))) > 1
     ~ "red", TRUE ~ "black")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value1, value2, colour = colr)) +
   geom_point() +
    scale_colour_identity()
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(value1 = c(2.3, 3.5, 3.1, 3.2, 2.4, 2.7, 2.5, 
2.9, 4.2, 2.2), value2 = c(0.1, 2.6, 2.5, 2.3, 1.1, 2.2, 3, 2, 
1, 1.5), condition1 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), condition2 = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), condition3 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```